# Console error for compiled Vue code in IE11 despite production environment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internet-explorer, rollupjs

I'm troubleshooting a browser compatibility issue with some custom code previously written to handle infinite scrolling on a staff directory for a Drupal 8 site: https://comartsci.msu.edu/directory As you scroll down the page, a new set of staff members loads in, 48 at a time, using Vue.

Here's a Gist containing my Gulpfile and the compiled views.js file: https://gist.github.com/KurtTrowbridge/eea0c25bd60eddd8fa7cbcd2c81e49e1

Internet Explorer 11 fails to load additional staff members beyond the initial set of 48. A console error suggests it's an issue with [line 26872](https://gist.github.com/KurtTrowbridge/eea0c25bd60eddd8fa7cbcd2c81e49e1#file-views-js-L26872): `Expected ':'` As I understand, those arrays and the functions they refer to originate from Lodash, so it's nothing originating in the Vue components or anywhere else that I can edit myself.

I know that when I've worked with Vue in the past, I have to [build it in a production-ready format](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html) in order for it to be compatible with IE11. I noticed that their Gulpfile uses rollup-plugin-babel as part of its compilation tasks, but that it was initially set to the `development` environment; I [tried switching it to `production`](https://gist.github.com/KurtTrowbridge/eea0c25bd60eddd8fa7cbcd2c81e49e1#file-gulpfile-js-L66), but still receive the same error.

Is there anything else here that indicates why IE11 is failing to run the JavaScript code, and what I can adjust in order to fix it?

Comment: I suggest you create a small sample which can produce the issue with IE 11 browser. It is difficult to check your whole GIST code. If you provide the sample then we can try to find a possible cause for this issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I updated the Gist to pare down the Gulpfile, but unfortunately, the views.js file consists mostly of compiled code from dependencies, so there's not much of a way I can see to make the sample smaller aside from pointing out the relevant problem areas that I wrote in my original comment. I did add two more files to the Gist for the Vue component, but I'm not sure how much sense they'll make out of context.

Comment: It is also difficult for us to check it. I suggest you create a paid support ticket for Microsoft. One Microsoft engineer will be assigned to look into this issue.